# Apply css to just one grid

Tags: css, jqgrid

I'm using jqgrid 4.5.4.

I'm trying to apply some css using this selectors

```
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td {
    word-wrap: break-word; /* IE 5.5+ and CSS3 */
    white-space: pre-wrap; /* CSS3 */
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
    white-space: -pre-wrap; /* Opera 4-6 */
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* Opera 7 */
    overflow: hidden;
    height: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

but since i have multiple grids and i just want to apply this css to a grid, i tried this way:

```
#grid .ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td {
    word-wrap: break-word; /* IE 5.5+ and CSS3 */
    white-space: pre-wrap; /* CSS3 */
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
    white-space: -pre-wrap; /* Opera 4-6 */
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* Opera 7 */
    overflow: hidden;
    height: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

but with no success.

Is there a way to apply this css to just one or two grids instead of all grids?

Comment: Add a class to the grid you want to change? Please share the html for a better help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector

```css
#grid .ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td {...}
```

is wrong because `.ui-jqgrid` is **outer** div relative to the grid. Correct would be at least the following:

```css
.ui-jqgrid #grid tr.jqgrow td {...}
```

see the structure of jqGrid divs and tables [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#grid-internal-div).

Answer (score 1):

Educated guess: You're targeting grid with `id="grid"` and `class="ui-jqgrid"`. Then, your CSS should target `#grid.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td` (no space between `#grid` and `.ui-jqgrid`).

As currently it targets `.ui-jqgrid` which would be **child** of `#grid` instead of the element.

So your code would be:

```
#grid.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td {
    word-wrap: break-word; /* IE 5.5+ and CSS3 */
    white-space: pre-wrap; /* CSS3 */
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
    white-space: -pre-wrap; /* Opera 4-6 */
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* Opera 7 */
    overflow: hidden;
    height: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```